# Converting Large .wav document to .txt with MsAzure Credentials with Free Account

Tags: python-3.x, azure, speech-to-text

I have the following Python Code which neither gives error nor produces any output.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

def from_file():
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="xxxx",region="xxxx")
    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename="Filepath//Audio.wav")
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config,  
    audio_config=audio_input)

result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
print(result.text)

from_file()
```

Can anybody suggest where I am going wrong? My .wav is a big file (file size > 50MB).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "continuous recognition", not "recognize_once" operation.

You have a full sample available for Python [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=script%2Cbrowser%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-python&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#continuous-recognition) in the doc

Comment: Hi Nicolas  I tried the way you suggested.
However the following portion of my Code gives me an error message.

def stop_cb(evt):
    print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    nonlocal done
    done = True

it returns the error "SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'done' found"

I tried with some solutions with stack overflow but those did not work either.

Can any body help me fix that?